# Use differentials to estimate the measurement errors in $m$ and $c$

Tags: calculus

We have $$W = 10 + 0.895m -12.33c^{0.18} + 12.33c^{0.18}$$

we calculate the differential of m, which is $0.895$ and the differential of $c$, which is something like $$-12.33/c^{0.82} + 12.33/c^{0.82}$$ and what then?

what do we do with $c$. I am confused...

Comment: The way you've written it, the terms involving $c$ cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have bounds on the errors in your measurements of $m$ and $c$, and you want to approximate the error in your estimate of $W$.

Use this:

\begin{equation}
W(m + \Delta m, c + \Delta c) \approx W(m,c) + \frac{\partial W(m,c)}{\partial m} \Delta m
+ \frac{\partial W(m,c)}{\partial c} \Delta c.
\end{equation}

This equation lets you see how large the quantity
$|W(m + \Delta m, c + \Delta c) - W(m,c)|$ might be.

Comment: can you explain what that equation is? the 2 rational terms are they derivatives?

Comment: Yes, they are the partial derivatives of $W$ with respect to $m$ and $c$. For example, $\frac{\partial W(m,c)}{\partial m} = .895$ in your problem.

Comment: why W(mc)?? someone told me you only need to compute the partial derivative of c and m

Comment: I wrote $W(m,c)$, not $W(mc)$.  $W$ is a function of $m$ and $c$.

Comment: in my book there iw no w(m,c), it's just the addition of two partial derivatives

Comment: Bring $w(m, c) $ over to the left hand side, and you see the sum of two partials approximates the error in $w$.